# In a bipartite graph finding the edges that are present in all maximum matchings

Tags: sage

Has anyone written up the algorithm in **Sage** given by Tamir Tassa in, ``Finding all maximally-matchable edges in a bipartite graph''?

Comment: Also asked at Also asked at https://ask.sagemath.org/question/42324/find-all-maximum-matchings-in-a-bipartite-graph-and-how-to-relabel-edges-of-a-bipartite-graph-in-sage/